# Don't understand this pytz AttributeError: 'UTC' object has no attribute 'utc_timezone'

Tags: python, airflow, utc, pytz

Problem:

```
execution_date_to_search_for = pytz.timezone('UTC').utc_timezone.localize(datetime.strptime((process["airflow_execution_date"]).replace("T", " "),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
[2019-02-20 11:56:42,673] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 661: Subtask kill_halted_tasks AttributeError: 'UTC' object has no attribute 'utc_timezone'
```

The link contains the source code I'm using to kill halted tasks on Airflow. I tried to change the time format, but it keeps throwing an error.

https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-maintenance-dags/blob/master/kill-halted-tasks/airflow-kill-halted-tasks.py

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
execution_date_to_search_for = pytz.timezone('UTC').localize(datetime.strptime((process["airflow_execution_date"]).replace("T", " "),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

Please raise issue to the maintainer in order to fix that issue too.